# Leaflet OpenStreetMap, отрисовать карты за разные года

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, leafletjs

Нужно достать OSM подложку в Leaflet.js двухлетней давности - с другими названиями областей (дело в том что в Казахстане появились три новых области в середине 2022 года). Но мне для визуализации нужна старая подложка. Может кто подскажет как? Гуглил не нашел. Но помню интуитивно натыкался что можно какой-то параметр использовать типа year="2022" или historical date - что-то в этом роде. Благодарю за любые подсказки куда можно копать